# How is this function returning the entire string?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have some CSV files to combine, all with the same headers. I have one function that grabs the first line (one of any of the files), and another that skips the first line of each file.

```
function getFirstLine() {
    Param(
        [string]$path
    )

    $reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $path
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    $reader.Close()
    return $line
}

function returnFile(){
    Param(
        [string]$path,
        [Int32]$skip
    )

    $reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $path
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $skip; $i++) {
        $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    $data = ''

    while ($reader.EndOfStream -eq $false) {
        $data += $reader.ReadLine() + "`n"
    }
    $reader.Close()
    return $data
}
```

I invoke: `$Data = returnFile -path $CSVs[$i] -skip 1`. `$CSVs` is type `System.Collections.Generic.List[String]`, and contains the paths to the files.

It is the `returnFile` function that baffles me. Despite skipping the first line, it returns the entire string. I've confirmed while debugging, before I hit `return`, that the string `$data` does not contain the first line.

Here is my PS version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  248
```

Comment: What makes you think the function would skip the first line? How are you invoking it?

Comment: for ($i=0; $i -lt $skip; $i++) {
        $reader.ReadLine()
    } reads the line without assigning it anywhere. I've also "stepped through" using ISE to confirm. Updated my post with how I invoke.

Comment: You don't discard the output of `$reader.ReadLine()`, so it's automatically returned along with the other non-captured output.

Comment: I wasn't aware this was even a thing, or at least if I explicitly return a value (than just saying return alone). Make that an answer so I can mark it.